# Cordova iOS >= 9.2 jQuery Load HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I have a cordova project that was working just fine, but since I've updated to cordova 6.0 and the new webview I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/adrian/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3ACC077E-9068-4352-A28B-4BD13124BE5B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A387F0D2-9445-4E1F-BF85-7AAF68CBA973/Vivre.app/www/images/icons/dest/index.html?_=1454590513181. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'html',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "./images/icons/dest/index.html",
    beforeSend: false,
    cache: false
}).done(function(data){
    $( "#js-svg-inline" ).append(data).hide();
});
```

Comment: Try to use a absolut url: `http://example.com/path/to/your/index.html`

Comment: @WayNe it's a local file in the cordova app

Comment: You need to use localhost, even if its local file because of cross domain policy

Comment: Have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

Comment: ok, so what would be the path for a local file in a cordova app?

Comment: Ok after some research it seems like cordova treets the www directory like the root of a webserver (sry for the wrong direction...). Have you set `<access origin="*" />` in your config.xml ?

Comment: Thanks @WayNe, yes, I did, I've also added all the stuff in the .plist file. I think I'm gonna have to find a workaround for the jQuery load.

Comment: It's a known issue on the WKWebView, you can't do local ajax calls unless you use a local web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody else runs into this issue, look like this is a known limitation of the wkwebview

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10143